# iOS -- look inside provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements

Is it possible to inspect the insides of a provisioning profile?  I am dealing with a code signing error because the entitlements do not match.  Fixing this is rather difficult as I don't know how to inspect the entitlements in the provisioning profile.  Hence I am shooting in the dark.

Related questions, none of which seem to help in my case:

- [Code sign error with Xcode 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410080/code-sign-error-with-xcode-3-2)
- [The executable was signed with invalid entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements)
- [iPhone Entitlements problem with XCode 4 for Ad Hoc distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449487/iphone-entitlements-problem-with-xcode-4-for-ad-hoc-distribution)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can also do a text dump by typing

```
security cms -D -i <prov>
```

FWIW

- `security` is to Administer Keychains, keys, certificates and the Security framework.
- `cms` is a command within the `security` framework it stands for Cryptographic Message Syntax
- `-D` is for decoding
- `-i` means infile    use infile as source of data (default: stdin)

Comment: getting following warning with this command:
security: SecPolicySetValue: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.

Comment: getting:
security: failed to add data to decoder: UNKNOWN (-8183(d)
security: problem decoding

Answer (score 9):

You can `more` (or `less`) it in the terminal (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal). Just respond with `y` to the question about viewing binary data.

The xml part is readable. For example you can view the `ApplicationIdentifierPrefix` and the `keychain-access-groups`. In the past those gave me some headaches.

Answer (score 8):

A number of [Quick Look plug-ins](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) have been developed to inspect provisioning profiles:

- https://github.com/chockenberry/Provisioning
- https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL

After installing, just select the provisioning profile file in Finder and press space!

[image: Quick Look plug-in for provisioning profiles]

Comment: The [here] link above has been stripped, and there is no indication anywhere what the name of the app is. This looks interesting. Can you give us a reference (as opposed to a live link)?

Comment: ch hockenberry's provisioning quicklook generator is great. It even extracts all the relevant information when applied to a .ipa file. Up till now I had to rename the file as a zip file, unpack it, search for the provisioning profile, dump the text from it, then grep for the bits I needed. Now it's all right there.

Answer (score 7):

No need for an external app. The quickest and easiest way to observe the contents on a mac is by clicking on the profile in the Finder. The preview will list the following things (as well as others):

- App ID Name
- App ID
- Team Name
- Creation, Expiration date
- Entitlements
- Certs
- Device whitelist

Answer (score 3):

Simply select the `embedded.mobileprovision` and `Open With...` your favorite **Text Editor**. It may show a variety of encoding errors, but the parts you're concerned with, such as Entitlements and other keys, should be readily visible:

```
0Å   *H÷ ¶0²10 +0 +0 Ì!YëýI¬nuèzÑöçö°
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>Your App Name</string>

    ...

    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        ...
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
```

Comment: FWIW the `embeded.mobileprovision` is something that is only made available when you're looking building into a device. otherwise you won't be able to find it. For more on its exact location see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117697/5175709)

Answer (score 0):

Right click and select "Get Info". It will show you certificates, provisioned devices and entitlements.