# Xcode Provisioning Profiles Location

Tags: xcode, xcode8, provisioning-profile, app-signing

Where are the Provisioning Profiles located in Xcode 8.3.3 within the project and/or file directory?

Comment: as a side note, assuming you're in the desired 'dev team' and have the correct access you should always be able to download provisioning profiles from developer portal. By correct access I mean some devs only have access to Development Provisioning Profiles, others have access to Distribution Provisioning Profiles...

Answer (score 257):

Where they have been for older versions of Xcode: `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`

Provisioning profiles are not stored with the project.  Xcode has a common area and the profile is pulled when you build and bundled with the ipa.

Comment: so `ipa = project + provisioning profile` or there are other things added to it?

Comment: The .ipa is essentially a .zip file with the compiled application with an embedded provisioning profile.

Comment: Given its not stored with the project, how do push notifications work without the profile on another developer's machine?

Comment: The push notification certificate is needed on the server that sends the push notifications to Apple's APNS server.  If you wanted multiple servers to be able to do so, you're have to copy the private key and cert to each server.  This question is about the provisioning profile for running the app.  If manually manage your code signing, you'd need to export the private key for the cert associated with the provisioning profile and import it onto the other developer's machine.

Comment: Still there for XCode 11.5 in 2020.

Answer (score 154):

1. Go to the Finder
2. From the “**Go**” menu navigate down to “**Go to Folder**” 
   or
3. Hit **Command+Shift+G** from the Mac OS X **desktop** or a **Finder** **window**
4. Search below Path

> `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

[image]

Comment: took me a while to find the go to folder option had to 2 finger click the finder icon

Comment: #3. for the win

Answer (score -2):

FWIW if you're building into a physical device, then if you dig through your derived data, you can find:

```
/Users/my_username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyCompanyName-ebd35ntnhtdhykyasixtkvjjqlcsu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CoolAppName.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

In the `Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos` directory you'll find your app name just like:

```
CoolAppName  // it won't have any `.app` extension or anything.
```

You just have to right click on it and hit 'show package contents' or just change directory to that...

then find a file with `.mobileprovision` extension.

Remember you won't find this if you're building with simulator, because simulators, don't need provisioning profiles.

### How to see what's inside?

Either just use Preview or see detailed instructions from [Dev Forums - Quinn](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/22943) on how to dump it. e.g.

```
$ security cms -D -i ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/8d04addd-d7f5-4872-bd48-f6885bb67433.mobileprovision
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct answer according to the question?!

Comment: Chera javabesh nist? I mean it's asking where is it stored, and I'm giving an answer for a very specific case only. That is when you build into a real device, then the provisioning profile can also be found on the device...

Comment: Na baba :)), Of course, there are various ways in order to achieve `mobileprovision` for instance you can find it in an `ipa` file but it seems the question point to the local path.