# Recover Xcode autogenerated provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have deleted by mistake my Xcode automatically generated provisioning profile from developer account. App id still exist. Is there any way where I can recover the provisioning profile generated by xcode or make the xcode generate new provisioning profile. On enabling the automatically manage signing option the xcode take the old provisioning profile but it is not visible in the developer account.

Comment: You cannot recover ad-hoc provisioning profile if you have deleted it from the developer account, better generate new ones.

Comment: @AnandYadav Its not getting generated automatically...How do i generate it automatically...

Comment: select your Xcode project in navigator and select target you will see automatically manage signing button check that

Comment: Yeah i have enabled that but no new profile is being generated xcode is still using the old profile which i deleted it from developer account.

Comment: Try generating it by yourself

Comment: Thats what i am doing... But I want to use automatically generated system...so that i dont have to change the profiles again and again in the settings...

Comment: How do you know it is using the old profile?  Are you looking in the the embedded.mobileprovision file? It would probably help to show your project code signing settings.

Comment: There is not profile in development and distribution section on developer account... And in xcode project settings it is showing the date when it was created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe when using newer versions of Xcode that you will see the Xcode generated provisioning profiles in the Member Center.  See [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70626) for more details.

If the old provisioning profile is still valid, Xcode will continue to use it.  It will only generate a new one if you have invalidated the old one somehow (revoking the cert, the profile expires, etc.)  If you go into the Xcode preferences, under Accounts, you will probably still see the old provisioning profile listed there.  Also, you can check for the local provisioing profiles at the location specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642752/3708242).

It would also be helpful for you to indicate **why** using the old profile would be a problem.  You specify that you deleted it, but don't really indicate **where** you deleted it.  Your local copy on your Mac in the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory? From the member center?  On an iOS test device?

Are you now unable to build to devices?  Are you worried the profile will expire sooner than you'd like, so you want to generate a new one to give you a full year of the app running on the device?