# Distribution Provision Profile doesn't include signing certificate iPhone Developer xxxx xxxx

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, testflight

I am trying to create a distribution profile. From scratch I deleted every certificate at KeyChain. I removed all provision profile using terminal method. I closed my Xcode. Then I followed this [link](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios) to create the distribution certificate and profiles. I followed the step correctly and I got the following results. I keep getting "No signing certificate"IOS development found" Please help.

## Edited

I then created the Development certificate following this [link](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/308242-how-do-i-create-a-development-profile-for-ios) and now I get different certificates name for Development and Distribution. My error is `Distribution Provision Profile doesn't include signing certificate iPhone Developer xxxx xxxx`

Please help, thanks.

[image: pic2]

[image: Pic 1]

[image: pic 5]

[image: pic 3]

[image: pic4]

[image: pic 6]

## After creating the development profile

[image: After creating the development profile]

## Why is my certificate different name for development and distribution, I followed the steps to create certificate. Why is it different name?

[image: pic 8]

[image: pic 9]

Comment: You cannot use the same certificate for development and distribution.  That is why they are different.   Also, your "Signing (Debug)" profile should be your iOS Development provisioning profile, "SFITNESS Develop".

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are not using Automatic code signing?

Comment: Xcode still believes the "SFITNESS Distri" profile is an iOS Development profile.  I would delete all your provisioning profiles from the Xcode location (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642752/3708242) quit Xcode, redownload the iOS Distribution provisioning profile and open it (it will launch Xcode).  Something is out of sync with your profiles and certs.

Answer (score 46):

FOR DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATES

On BuildSettings make sure you pick "IOS Distribution" instead of "IOS DEVELOPER" in the "Code Signing Identity" dropdown:

[image]

Comment: Saved my day, Thank you :)

Comment: you  save  my  day

Comment: saved my..night

Comment: Wow. That saved 3 hours of mine.

Comment: you made my day. Thanks

Comment: Dude... THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have the certificate and provisioning profile for **iOS Distribution**. You are trying to do a build for **development** (building to a test device), which will require you to generate a certificate and profile for **iOS Development**.  Follow the steps you did, but when you need to specificy what the certificate is for, choose iOS Development.  Also, when you create the provisioning profile,  select  iOS Development.  It is actually the next article on the site you were using: http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/308242-how-do-i-create-a-development-profile-for-ios

The iOS Distribution certificate / profile will be used when you want to submit to Apple for testing through TestFlight, or for distribution in the App Store, so don't worry about deleting those.

Comment: I am trying to put it to the App Store already finish development, do I still need to create a development provisioning profile?

Comment: If you are trying to go to the app store, it is pretty risky to do so without testing it on a physical device.  You need a development profile to do that.  Technically, however, to build for the app store, you only need the distribution profile.  What are your code signing settings for your project under Signing (Release)? What are you doing to create your app store build?

Comment: I actually did create a development provisioning profile and tested it on physical device. I deleted it temperorary because I want to focus on the distribution provision profile and send it to the App Store for  test flight. However I keep getting the error. Anyway sorry I only can update you about your question in another 10hours later coz the pc is not with me.

Comment: OK, but the main problem is whatever you are doing to build the app think it should be doing a development build instead of a distribution build.  You need to make some changes either to you code signing settings, or your scheme to ensure you are trying to do a release build.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem and I solved it just checking the configuration of certificates and provisioning.

[Check if they are using correct provisioning profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvKEG.jpg)

[And check if they are using the correct reference in code signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVmuJ.jpg)

That's what worked for me...