# Not able to install Production/Distribution Sign iOS .ipa using ideviceinstaller

Tags: ios, sideloading, libimobiledevice, app-store-distribution-profile

In my MacBook-Pro v11.3.1 in which I installed:

1. libimobiledevice
2. ideviceinstaller (https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller)

**Expecting:**

- Application Side loading is required.
- Any option by which iOS can install to end user iPhone, directly.

I tried ideviceinstaller to install iOS app,

- Success for Developer Sign Provisional Profile.
- FAIL for Production/Distribution Sign Provisional Profile.

--Installation FAIL at

```
Install: CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install: ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install: InspectingPackage (20%)
Install: TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install: PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install: InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install: VerifyingApplication (40%)ERROR: Install failed. Got error "ApplicationVerificationFailed" with code 0xe8008016: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.0H6RXs/extracted/mInspect.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
```

**HOW TO ACHIEVE Production/Distribution Sign Provisional Profile iOS app to install using ideviceinstaller or any other option (Excluding MDM/ABM)?**

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you haven't signed your .ipa appropriately. To get a provisioning file, you will need to fetch it from Apple's servers using your account.

You can look into using or reimplementing [AltSign](https://github.com/rileytestut/AltSign/tree/swift_rewrite) by rileytestut, or you can get provisioning files from Xcode by creating an iOS app, giving it a bundle ID and choosing your personal team. Your provisioning profile will be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625347/xcode-provisioning-profiles-location)

Once you have your provisioning profile, you will need to sign your .ipa with it. You can use a tool like [ldid](https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/Ldid) or a wrapper on it like [XReSign](https://github.com/xndrs/XReSign). Your .ipa will then be ready to sideload!